# bootstrap-responsive overrides my .container width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have encountered an annoying "problem" with my web site, using Twitter Bootstrap. I have a main container using the default .container bootstrap class and I have given it a specific width in my custom css file. However, when I included the bootstrap-responsive.css file into my HTML document, it seems to override the width of my container.

This is the order of my CSS files:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Site.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
```

For what reason is there a width specified in the responsive css file? Is there a smooth way of fixing this without manually editing the bootstrap-responsive.css (which I reckon would be a bad idea)

I need the bootstrap-responsive.css in order to make my site mobile/tablet-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is min-width in bootstrap that is necessary to maintain proper structure. On the other hand, you can just simply put your css code **AFTER** bootstrap responsive so your rule will overwrite bootstrap's rule.

Comment: true..I'm just afraid I'll override more than I really want if I do that :S

Comment: change the order of Site.css and bootstrap-responsive.css

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I tend to load my own custom stylesheet after all other CSS files. But then, you have to make sure not to change any default values for global properties... or layout related properties i.e.: **.container**

In general, this class is re-used multiple times and might be adjusted for different devices and situations. So, I suggest to change such values in bootstrap-responsive.css This is the file, which contains all your media-queries.

Otherwise you end up with overriding your desired responsiveness, and that might result in CSS properties with !important exceptions. This should be avoided by all means.

Answer (score 0):

When you use CSS, the last instance of a piece of styling information takes priority. For example if I link to two different style sheets, the second one will take priority if there is a conflict...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

In this example, if the .container element is changes in the style.css file, the styling data in style.css will only take priority if there is a conflict. This effect is similar to having both external and inline CSS in a single HTML document. [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/777a4/) to illustrate. Here you see that the inline styling took priority and made the color of the text orange, while keeping the background black.